# What is the difference between value and !!value in angular?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between value and !!value in angular? What is the result or meaning of the following code?

```
return !!this.value;
//can I use this.value for this statement?
```

and

```
if (!!value){//can I use if(this.value) for this statement?
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It just converts that `this.value` into `boolean` value.